# How can I get local x11 display of gtk4-rs program working?

Tags: rust, x11, gtk4

I'm using ssh to remotely log in to a development machine with the -Y command line option to enable trusted X11 forwarding.  I think that my DISPLAY variable is getting set correctly because I can run xterm or gvim and the corresponding application windows pop up on my local machine.

However, if I build a trivial gtk4 hello world program and run it, either (1) if I'm logged in to the remote machine it displays on the remote machine or (2) if I'm not logged in to the remote machine it displays on the local machine after pausing for about 30 seconds and showing a couple libEGL errors.

How do I get my hello world gtk4-rs example to promptly display on my local machine regardless of whether I'm logged in to the remote machine ( as xterm and gvim and other well behaved x11 windowing programs do )

My local computer is running ubuntu 22.04 .    The remote computer is an Ubuntu 23.04 (beta) virtual box but I've also tried ubuntu 22.04 as the remote computer.

Here's my hello world program:

```
use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::{Application, ApplicationWindow};

fn main() {
    let app = Application::builder()
        .application_id("org.example.HelloWorld")
        .build();

    app.connect_activate(|app| {
        // We create the main window.
        let window = ApplicationWindow::builder()
            .application(app)
            .default_width(320)
            .default_height(200)
            .title("Hello, World!")
            .build();

        // Show the window.
        window.show();
    });

    app.run();
}
```

Here's my cargo.toml :

```
[package]
name = "gtk_helloworld"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
gtk = { version = "0.6.1", package = "gtk4", features = ["v4_8"] }
```

Comment: Have you tried with other Gtk4 applications? This would tell us if the issue is with Gtk4 itself, or the Rust bindings. Note that `gvim` uses Gtk3 and `xterm` doesn't use Gtk at all…

Comment: Per your question, I ran a couple of tests.    The symptoms reproduce with the gtk4 and gtk3 example-0.c programs so the rust bindings are not the problem and neither is gtk4.  See: https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/getting_started.html and https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/getting_started.html  .     The symptoms also reproduce with the gnote (gtk3) application but, as I mentioned in the original question, not with gvim which appears to be gtk3 also.

Comment: Per: https://docs.gtk.org/gdk3/func.set_allowed_backends.html , gtk tries to use a series of backends for display.    If I export environment variable GDK_BACKEND=x11 before running my application, then the window appear immediately on my local machine IF I'm logged in to the remote machine.   This is not perfect but it's an improvement.